# Parse Python String for Units

Tags: python, units-of-measurement

Say I have a set of strings like the following:

```
"5 m^2"
"17 sq feet"
"3 inches"
"89 meters"
```

Is there a Python package which will read such strings, convert them to SI, and return the result in an easily-usable form? For instance:

```
>>> a=dream_parser.parse("17 sq feet")
>>> a.quantity
1.5793517
>>> a.type
'area'
>>> a.unit
'm^2'
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/units is good, but I don't think it'll parse the units out of a string for you.

Comment: Here's another one: https://pint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python library to convert between SI unit prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969759/python-library-to-convert-between-si-unit-prefixes)

Comment: This is a non-duplicate @BurhanKhalid. I am not interested in purely SI prefixes and do not assume that the units are already known by the programmer/user: string parsing is a must.

Comment: I meant that the solutions in the answer could provide a starting point.

Comment: @isedev, Pint has some of the features I'm looking for, though the string processing is a little more rudimentary than I'd like.

Answer (score 6):

[Quantulum](https://pypi.org/project/quantulum/) will do exactly what you described

Excerpt from its description:

```
from quantulum import parser

quants = parser.parse('I want 2 liters of wine') 

# quants [Quantity(2, 'litre')]
```

Comment: This is great but it doesn't work for multi-dimensions like 273x27x27 mm...

Comment: Doesn't work with Python 3, last release was in August 2016.

Comment: There is a python 3 version, Quantulum3

Answer (score 3):

More recently, [pint](http://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/) is a good place to start for most of these.

Answer (score 2):

Is there an extension for ipython that can do at least part of what you want. It's called [ipython-physics](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/ipython-physics)

It does store value and units and allows (at least) some basic math. I have never used it myself, so I don't know how easy would be to use in a python script

Comment: I see. I just gave a look at the source, and it seems to me that Ipython enters only when loading/unloading the extension, non in the body of the extension itself. But I guess that the `pint` wins, if not for the name and the picture

Answer (score 2):

If you have '**nice**' strings then use [pint](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint).

(best for unit conversions)

```py
import pint
u = pint.UnitRegistry()
value = u.quantity("89 meters")
```

If you have **text/sentences** then use [quantulum](https://github.com/marcolagi/quantulum)

```py
from quantulum import parser

value = parser.parse('Pass me a 300 ml beer.')
```

If you have '**ugly**' strings then use try [unit_parse](https://github.com/dylanwal/unit_parse).

Examples of 'ugly' strings: (see [unit_parse](https://github.com/dylanwal/unit_parse) github for more examples)

```
2.3 mlgcm --> 2.3 cm * g * ml
5E1 g/mol --> 50.0 g / mol
5 e1 g/mol --> 50.0 g / mol
()4.0 (°C) --> 4.0 °C
37.34 kJ/mole (at 25 °C) --> [[<Quantity(37.34, 'kilojoule / mole')>, <Quantity(25, 'degree_Celsius')>]]
Detection in water: 0.73 ppm; Chemically pure --> 0.73 ppm
```

(uses [pint](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint) under the hood)

```py
from unit_parse import parser

result = parser("1.23 g/cm3 (at 25 °C)")
print(result) # [[<Quantity(1.23, 'g / cm ** 3')>, <Quantity(25, 'degC')>]]
```