# How to convert SI units to number using python

Tags: python, numbers, integer

I want to convert the numbers which come with the letters and convert it based on the value each letter specifies. Like a number 1M should be read as 1000000 and a number 1K should be read as 1000. Is there some simple method to get this done?

Comment: You could try writing some code to solve your problem :)

Comment: I saw the [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.2/) library referenced in another answer a few days ago. I haven't used it myself but it may be suitable for you. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python library to convert between SI unit prefixes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969759/python-library-to-convert-between-si-unit-prefixes)

Answer (score 2):

A trivial approach would be to use a dictionary to store the number of zeros each conversion would use:

```
>>> si_units = {
...     'K': 3,
...     'M': 6
... }
>>> 
>>> var = '5M'
>>> int(var[0]) * (10 ** si_units[var[1]])
5000000
>>> var = '2K'
>>> int(var[0]) * (10 ** si_units[var[1]])
2000
>>>
```

This solution may or may not be scalable depending on the size and complexity of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the last character to a value, e.g. M -> 1000000, k -> 1000.
Multipy with the value and add some code for possible parse errors.

(I deliberately did not add code here to let you give it a try).

Comment: Michel, I just needed to know if this should be done by writing some code or if there was a simple function. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok ... I didn't knew that from the question ... afaik there is no function, but it cannot be that hard to write it after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prefixed](https://pypi.org/project/prefixed/) to convert to a float. [prefixed.Float](https://prefixed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#prefixed.Float) is a subclass of the builtin float and is the same except it allows formatting with SI and IEC prefixes.

```
>>> from prefixed import Float
>>> Float('1M')
Float(1000000.0)
```

If you want an integer

```
>>> int(Float('1M'))
1000000
```

If you want to convert back, just add `'h'` as a format specifier and use '.#' to set precision.

```
>>> value = Float('1M')
>>> f'{value:.0h}'
'1M'
>>> f'{value:.2h}'
'1.00M'
```

In the case of 1K, that's not SI notation, the prefix for kilo is k, so you'd need to make it lowercase. Just be careful with those because M is Mega and m is Milli. Pretty big difference there! Supported prefixes are listed [here](https://prefixed.readthedocs.io/en/stable/prefixes.html#supported-prefixes).

```
>>> Float('1K'.lower())
Float(1000.0)
```

If K is for kibi, you need to add an `'i'` so it Prefixed knows you want IEC prefixes,

```
>>> Float('1Ki')
Float(1024.0)
```