# How to format a float with a SI prefix (k, M...) in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting, units-of-measurement

I have a float, say 1762423.55, which I want to format as 1.76M, i.e. with three significant digits and with a SI prefix.

In Javascript this accessible with the `s` type in [`d3.format`](https://github.com/d3/d3-format).

But in Python,

```py
'{:s}'.format(1762423.55)
```

fails with a `ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'float'`.

Is the SI format accessible through another **standard type format** in Python? If not, where on GitHub should I ask for it?

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32093034/6045800)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'd prefer not to use an additional script or library - anyone knows where on GitHub I can ask (or contribute) that feature to `str.format`?

Comment: @MarcWouts you could ask but that doesn't mean they would add it straight away. The beauty of Python is that you can extend it with your desired behaviour through functions and methods given a base set of functionality.